# Dual monitors waking from sleep very slow?

Tags: display, sleep-wake, mac-pro

I have 2 EIZO screens via Thunderbolt/Display port connected to my MacPro (2013 cylinder).

One day I press a key and the screen comes on straight away after sleep, the other day it can easily take 20-30 seconds. I can not find any pattern.

I'm pretty sure the mac self wakes-up, its just the signal to the screens that is in some cases delayed.

Anybody an idea what might to cause that?

Thanks!

Comment: if you go to console you will find that in case it is slow, it spends a lot of time negotiating the handshake with the monitor. This could be cause by cable (make sure it sits firm) or the monitor it self. What kind of plug is it on both ends

Comment: @buscar thanks. I can't access the console when the screens aren't up? There display adapters (monitor) and thundertbolt on the mac (I wrote it).

Comment: asfor the console log, just remember the time, and you can open it and go back in history till that time stamp. I know it is thunderbolt, what exactly is on the other end ? what is display adapter ?

Comment: @buscar sorry displayport I mean, ill check the console log

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your cables are good and connected firmly, I would try resetting the NVRAM and SMC (in that order).

**Resetting NVRAM**

Your Mac use Non-Volatile Random-Access Memory (NVRAM) to store a whole range of settings. Here’s how to reset this:

1. **Shut down your Mac.** Yes, a full shut down, not just logging out.
2. Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> *and then* press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> keys. You have to make sure you press these keys **before** the gray screen appears or it won’t work.
3. **Hold those keys down** until your Mac reboots again and you here the startup chime for the second time.
4. Let go of the keys and let your Mac reboot normally.

**Note:** When you log back in you ***may*** need to readjust some of your system preferences (e.g. speaker volume, screen resolution, startup disk selection, time zone information, etc).

**Resetting SMC on a Mac Pro**

Follow these steps for resetting the SMC on your Mac Pro:

1. Fully Shut Down your Mac Pro
2. Unplug the AC power cord
3. Wait at least 15 seconds
4. Plug the AC power cord back in
5. Wait at least 5 seconds
6. Switch on your Mac Pro

Now use your Mac Pro as usual to determine if the problem still occurs. If so, try using your Mac in Safe Mode for a while to see if the problem occurs.

**Booting into Safe Mode**

Follow these steps to boot your Mac Pro into Safe Mode:

1. Fully shut down your Mac Pro
2. Restart your Mac Pro
3. Immediately press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and **keep it down**
4. Let go of the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when you see the login window (NOTE: If you have FileVault enabled you may need to log in twice).
5. Take a note of what happens (i.e. did your Mac Pro boot okay, are you still having issues with your screens waking up, etc)
6. Once you've tested long enough, exit Safe Mode by restart your Mac as normal

Let me know how you went and we'll go from there.