# MacOS detects displays in the wrong order

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display

I have two external displays, one Dell 75hz, and one Gigabyte 144hz, however, for some reason, my mac thinks the Dell is the Gigabyte and vice versa. This is frustrating as I can't utilize the higher framerate on my main display since it simply won't show as an option because it thinks it is the other display.

I attached are some screenshots to show what I mean:[image]

[image]

I already tried detecting for displays again by pressing option in the Display settings that however did not work.

This is on MacOS Monterey 12.0.1 and its a 2020 Mac Book pro

Comment: What version of macOS? Also - are the displays recognized correctly when plugged in individually? When you have the system booted, and you plug in the displays one by one, are they recognized correctly, or do they switch once both are connected?

Comment: Dropping the [model year of Mac Pro in the text of the post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/346465/5472) with an edit might help us  confirm the discovery is arbitrary or suggest cabling options that result in a more dependable layout once the OS takes over

Comment: just edited it @bmike